# API to convert lat lon to NYC neighborhood

Tags: google-maps, heroku, geocoding

Is there a hosted API that converts a latitude and longitude into a Manahttan neighborhood?

I know that Zillow has a [shapefile](https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm) but I'd much rather just use an API.

I've looked a [few](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2046/converting-geographic-coordinates-to-new-york-city-neighboorhood-names) [questions](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-an-API-for-mapping-coordinates-to-neighborhoods). It looks like NYC open [data](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/Neighborhood-Names-GIS/99bc-9p23/data) also has neighborhood information.

The closest I've come to finding an API that takes lat lon is the times [Districts](https://open.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/07/01/introducing-the-districts-api/) API but it seems to be deprecated as it's not on their list of API's and the links redirect to those lists.

Is there a publicly available API? Or do I need to create a heroku app with a zillow shapefile and create my own?

Google maps only returns manhattan in its geocoding response, not a specific neighborhood in Manhattan

Comment: What do you mean by the "specific neighborhood" in Manhattan?  Upper East Side?

Comment: @geocodezip yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [MapBox API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#geocoding) for reverse geocoding and parse the JSON data obtained to extract the Neighborhood name.
I made a small example that you can inspire from.

Code:

```js
//You can get your access_token if needed from mapbox.com
var access_token = '?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw';
var urlInit = 'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/';
var mode = 'mapbox.places/';
var type = '&types=neighborhood';

$('#go').click(function() {
  $('#result').html('');
  lonlatInput = $('#lonlat').val();
  lonlatInput = lonlatInput.split(',');
  lonlat = lonlatInput[0].trim() + '%2C' + lonlatInput[1].trim() + '.json';
  getNeighborhood(lonlat);
});

function getNeighborhood(lonlat) {
  var url = urlInit + mode + lonlat + access_token + type;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    success: function(rgeo) {
      var result = rgeo;
      var neighborhood = rgeo.features[0].text;
      $('#result').html(neighborhood);
    },
    error: function(rgeo) {
      console.log(rgeo);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#result {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="-73.945462,40.830182" id="lonlat" />
<button id="go">Geocode</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

See [this example](https://fiddle.jshell.net/2m78nqvo/1/) in JsFiddle

Comment: sorry I didn't see this early to give full bounty! @mydsi

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of solutions to your objective such as **CartoDB integrations**, **Bing Location API**, **geopy**, **geocoder**, **SmartyStreets API** and others.

Let us explore this using **[CartoDB](https://carto.com/)**:

Create a file with longitude and latitude coordinates in NYC.

Use an NYC neighborhoods geometry file from [Zillow](https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm)

Upload the files to Cartodb and geoencode the longitude and latitude coordinates as a geometry object in your longitude and latitude coordinate file.

Run the following SQL query from within the file:

```
SELECT a.*, 
       b.neighborhood 
FROM inputFileName
as a, 
   nyc_pediacities_neighborhoods_v3_polygon as b 
WHERE ST_Within(a.the_geom,b.the_geom)
```

We are creating two objects, `inputFile` as `a` and the `shapefile` as `b`, then match the geometries against one another with the WHERE clause.

We are creating a new column with rows denoting the NYC neighborhood of the longitude and latitude of the same row.

Simply export the file in a desirable format and enjoy the information.

One can easily automate the process using one of their integrations. This will closely act as an ideal API. See [this](https://carto.com/integrations/)

The python package **`geopy`** also deserves attention. Check [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy/1.9.1)

One can achieve the same result using the Bing Location API. See [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx)

Another feasible solution is to construct your own **API** from the open data.

Check [geocoder](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/alexreisner/geocoder/master/frames) and [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com/docs)